# Pictures do not render well on Firefox for Android

Tags: bug, markdown, mobile-web, firefox

The pictures included in a post (see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/47416/3044)) are apparently not resized to fit in Firefox for Android (I tried on Android app, Chrome for Android, and the default browser and it seems ok on these). Large pictures go out of the window.

One workaround is to specify the size of the picture, but [as far as I know](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img), markdown does not handle resizing the pictures, so it requires regular HTML `img` tags. The other workaround is to include a smaller picture, but that's not always an available option.

Comment: firefox is getting creepy now a days ...

Comment: Doesn't appear limited to Android. The desktop version of Firefox does the same thing when switched to mobile view.